# Next-auth in Next13 app router returns unexpected responses on signIn

Tags: authentication, credentials, next-auth, next.js13, app-router

Using Next-Auth in Next13 app router behavios unexpectedly. I used "next": "13.4.13",
"next-auth": "^4.23.1", in my projext for authentication. I uses credentials provider for signin and on sucessfull signin using username and password the signin response sould be {error:null, ok:true}, but I always recives a sessionExpired Error and for unsuccessfull signin the ok flag sould be 'false' but I recives it as 'true'

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Sign in",
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "Email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "example@example.com",
                },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {

                if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
                    return null;
                }
                try {
                    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                        where: { email: credentials?.email }, select: {
                            id: true,
                            name: true,
                            email: true,
                            avatar: true,
                            password: true,
                        },
                    })
                    if (!user) return null
                    // const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(credentials?.password!, user.password)
                    const isMatch = credentials.password === user.password
                    if (isMatch) {
                        return {
                            id: user.id,
                            name: user.name,
                            email: user.email,
                            image: user.avatar
                        }
                    }
                    return null
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log({ error })
                    throw new Error('Server Error')
                }

            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth/login',
        signOut: '/auth/login'
    },
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    session: { strategy: "jwt" },
};
```